# Do you need to make your current class IDisposable if using an IDisposable field in a using statement?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Here's my example:

```
public sealed class BigLogicClass
{
    private SmallDisposableClass fMyDisposableClass;

    public void Setup(someParam)
    {
        var eventHandlerFactory = new EventHandlerFactory();
        var eventHandler = eventHandlerFactory.Create(someParam);
        eventHandler.SomeEvent += OnDoingThisEvent;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using(fMyDisposableClass = new SmallDisposableClass())
        {
            // run a long process.
        }
    }

    private void OnDoingThisEvent()
    {
        fMyDisposableClass.RunSomething();
    }
}
```

I have a method 'OnDoingThisEvent' in this class that is invoked elsewhere by another class 'eventHandler'. 'OnDoingThisEvent' needs to be able to use 'fMyDisposableClass'. However, doing it like this raises a code analysis error that basically suggests that 'fMyDisposableClass' is not being disposed of properly.

The only place it is instantiated is in a `using statement`, which encompasses the life time of the process for which 'fMyDisposableClass' should live. During this process 'OnDoingThisEvent' can be invoked. Presumably this means the instance of 'fMyDisposableClass' will be disposed of once that process completes. So is this an issue? If so, how would I be able to go about using 'fMyDisposableClass' without making 'BigLogicClass' disposable and then implementing dispose?

Comment: I don't see how this ensures that eventhandler does not fires that event while fMyDisposableClass does not exists or is disposed. Setup&DoSomething should be only one surfaced method so a class user can't fumble here and attach/detach the event in the using block and not somewhere else.

Comment: Keeping a reference to a disposed object is not a great idea, be sure to reliably generate an ObjectDisposedException.  Do favor passing the object as a method argument.  But no, it's dead when the lifetime of the BigLogicClass object expires so you don't have to make it even more dead.

Comment: @HansPassant - ok, sounds like whilst this isn't ideal, it shouldn't cause a problem. The fMyDisposableClass should only live for the length of the process. The 'OnDoingThisEvent' should only be able to be called during that process, so in theory nothing should ever try and call fMyDisposableClass once it's disposed. However, adding an ObjectDisposedException should hopefully be enough.

Answer (score 1):

In your current implementation (which is *suspicious*) there's *no need* to declare the class as `IDisposable`, since class *doesn't own* unmanaged resources. The class methods *allocates* and then *free* some resources, and that's all: the class itself doesn't own these resources:

```
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Some resources are allocated here...
        using(fMyDisposableClass = new SmallDisposableClass())
        {
            // run a long process.
        }
        // ...and releases here
    }

    private void OnDoingThisEvent()
    {
        // Note, that fMyDisposableClass can be disposed here
        // Any calls - RunSomething - are very suspicious.
        fMyDisposableClass.RunSomething();
    }
```

You, probably, what something like this:

```
public sealed class BigLogicClass
{
    // Instance doesn't own unmanaged resources   

    public void Setup(someParam)
    {
        var eventHandlerFactory = new EventHandlerFactory();
        var eventHandler = eventHandlerFactory.Create(someParam);
        eventHandler.SomeEvent += OnDoingThisEvent;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (var myDisposableClass = new SmallDisposableClass())
        {
            // run a long process.

            ...

            // Fire event using myDisposableClass which is not disposed yet 
            OnDoingThisEvent(myDisposableClass);  

            ... 
        }
    }

    private void OnDoingThisEvent(SmallDisposableClass myClass)
    {
        myClass.RunSomething();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** if you want to fire an event

```
    ...
    private void OnDoingThisEvent(SmallDisposableClass myClass)
    {
        myClass.RunSomething();

        // Let user 
        EventHandler someEvent = SomeEvent;

        if (someEvent != null)
        { 
            someEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        } 
    }

    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    ...
```

Comment: `eventHandler.SomeEvent += OnDoingThisEvent;` How does eventHandler know about myClass it should provide when calling the method?

Comment: @Ralf: if you want to fire an event, you can do it with `OnDoingThisEvent`: please, see my edit